# transform structure of list of lists and write it on the same sheets in excel

Tags: r, list

Lets simulate some data

```
x1<-rnorm(5,1,1)
x2<-rnorm(5,1,1)
x3<-rnorm(5,1,1)
x4<-rnorm(5,1,1)

a<-rep("a",5)
b<-rep("b",5)
c<-rep("c",5)
d<-rep("d",5)
```

Here I made bunch of vectors which I want to combine into data frames

```
vec<-c("x1", "x2","x3", "x4", "a", "b", "c", "d")


creator <- function(vec) {
  # Identify the different groups of vectors
  x_vecs <- grep("x", vec, value = TRUE)
  other_vecs <- setdiff(vec, x_vecs)
  
  # Initialize an empty list to store the output data frames
  out_list <- list()
  
  # Loop through all combinations of one vector from each group
  for (x in x_vecs) {
    for (other in other_vecs) {
      # Combine the two vectors into a data frame and assign a name
      new_df <- data.frame(get(x), get(other))
      names(new_df) <- c(x, other)
      new_name <- paste(x, other, sep = "")
      
      # Add the new data frame to the output list
      out_list[[new_name]] <- new_df
    }
  }
  
  # Return the list of output data frames
  return(out_list)
}
```

Here is a function that combines different "vector types" ("x" vectors are one group and "abcd" vectors are another) into data frames and stores them into a list

```
l1<-creator(vec) 
View(l1)
```

Here I extract list elements and combine them into smaller lists based on x number

```
lx1<-l1[1:4]
lx2<-l1[5:8]
lx3<-l1[9:12]
lx4<-l1[13:16]
```

Here I create list of lists.

```
listx1234<-list(lx1,lx2,lx3, lx4)
View(list1234)
```

What I would like to do next is, change list structure from each list in a list containing same x value and changing letter (abcd) value into a list that contains same "a","b","c","d" value and changing x value "x1","x2","x3","x4".

So basically, from listx1234-> listfinal where list elements will be lists with following structure:

```
# dont run this:
l2a<-list(x1a,x2a,x3a,x4a)
l2b...
l2c...
l2d...

listfinal<-list(l2a,l2b,l2c,l2d)
```

And at the end, I want to write lists in the same excel file, every sheet will get name a,b,c,d... and all the list elements from listfinal will end up on the corresponding sheet.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this?

```r
l2 <- lapply(seq_along(listx1234), \(i) {
  l <- lapply(listx1234, `[[`, i)
  setNames(l, paste0("x", seq_along(l)))
})
names(l2) <- sapply(l2, \(l) names(l$x1)[2])

l2
#> $a
#> $a$x1
#>            x1 a
#> 1  0.91621564 a
#> 2  0.01705625 a
#> 3 -0.87506732 a
#> 4  0.81385534 a
#> 5  0.36651430 a
#> 
#> $a$x2
#>           x2 a
#> 1 2.09079746 a
#> 2 0.08627273 a
#> 3 2.00163971 a
#> 4 0.60073340 a
#> 5 0.53187695 a
#> 
#> $a$x3
#>          x3 a
#> 1 1.3269621 a
#> 2 0.5872531 a
#> 3 1.5620365 a
#> 4 1.6633583 a
#> 5 0.3971027 a
#> 
#> $a$x4
#>         x4 a
#> 1 1.698378 a
#> 2 1.595846 a
#> 3 1.452092 a
#> 4 1.896744 a
#> 5 1.572217 a
#> 
#> 
#> $b
#> $b$x1
#>            x1 b
#> 1  0.91621564 b
#> 2  0.01705625 b
#> 3 -0.87506732 b
#> 4  0.81385534 b
#> 5  0.36651430 b
#> 
#> $b$x2
#>           x2 b
#> 1 2.09079746 b
#> 2 0.08627273 b
#> 3 2.00163971 b
#> 4 0.60073340 b
#> 5 0.53187695 b
#> 
#> $b$x3
#>          x3 b
#> 1 1.3269621 b
#> 2 0.5872531 b
#> 3 1.5620365 b
#> 4 1.6633583 b
#> 5 0.3971027 b
#> 
#> $b$x4
#>         x4 b
#> 1 1.698378 b
#> 2 1.595846 b
#> 3 1.452092 b
#> 4 1.896744 b
#> 5 1.572217 b
#> 
#> 
#> $c
#> $c$x1
#>            x1 c
#> 1  0.91621564 c
#> 2  0.01705625 c
#> 3 -0.87506732 c
#> 4  0.81385534 c
#> 5  0.36651430 c
#> 
#> $c$x2
#>           x2 c
#> 1 2.09079746 c
#> 2 0.08627273 c
#> 3 2.00163971 c
#> 4 0.60073340 c
#> 5 0.53187695 c
#> 
#> $c$x3
#>          x3 c
#> 1 1.3269621 c
#> 2 0.5872531 c
#> 3 1.5620365 c
#> 4 1.6633583 c
#> 5 0.3971027 c
#> 
#> $c$x4
#>         x4 c
#> 1 1.698378 c
#> 2 1.595846 c
#> 3 1.452092 c
#> 4 1.896744 c
#> 5 1.572217 c
#> 
#> 
#> $d
#> $d$x1
#>            x1 d
#> 1  0.91621564 d
#> 2  0.01705625 d
#> 3 -0.87506732 d
#> 4  0.81385534 d
#> 5  0.36651430 d
#> 
#> $d$x2
#>           x2 d
#> 1 2.09079746 d
#> 2 0.08627273 d
#> 3 2.00163971 d
#> 4 0.60073340 d
#> 5 0.53187695 d
#> 
#> $d$x3
#>          x3 d
#> 1 1.3269621 d
#> 2 0.5872531 d
#> 3 1.5620365 d
#> 4 1.6633583 d
#> 5 0.3971027 d
#> 
#> $d$x4
#>         x4 d
#> 1 1.698378 d
#> 2 1.595846 d
#> 3 1.452092 d
#> 4 1.896744 d
#> 5 1.572217 d
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Yeah, something like this, thanks, but I would also like to write these lists into excel based on "abcd" columns where each sheet would get 1 list ("a", "b"....etc). If you would have idea how to do it, great!

Comment: @procerus I cannot do it right now, work calls, but I will return to it today.